# Import gif file to SSIS and save binary, filename etc to table fields

Tags: ssis, binary, load, gif

I need to use SSIS to cycle through a bunch of .gif images in a folder and import each one into a single row in a table, which contains fields such as filename and size, but more crucially, the binary from the file.

I will use a foreach loop to cycle through the files, and probably a script transformation to assign variables to certain outputs but what I am having difficulty with is dealing with the .gif file itself and handling the binary within the data flow. I'm not sure:

1. what connection manager to use and how to configure it
2. what data source to use

From googling this I think I need to also use a column transformation at some point to handle the binary but it's not obvious how I use or configure it.

If anyone has any experience with this, some pointers would be much appreciated.

Glenn

Comment: must you use SSIS or can the solution be a simple console app?

Comment: SSIS fits in with our architecture for file processing, and we process a lot of files. Would prefer an SSIS solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your datasource or using a derived column transform you work out the path to your file you need to import. Then add in an Import Column Transformation, selecting your file path column. The Import column transform needs to have a binary column which can then be used in the dataflow destination. There's an example [here](http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/09/the-import-column-transformation/)